# getJSON how to set data to array?

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

I'm an amateur programmer so go easy on me. I am trying to call getJson only once to pull an array, then have jquery autocomplete use that as a source. It seems like this code is never calling the handler.

```
<script>   

$(function () {
        var availableTags[];
        $.getJSON("./Handler.ashx", function(data) {
            availableTags = data;
        });

        $("#TextBox3").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
</script>
```

the code below works but I do not want js to call the handler every time .

```
<script>        
$(function () {
        $("#TextBox3").autocomplete({
            source: "./Handler.ashx",
            minLength: 3,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).val(ui.item.value);
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<script>   

$(function () {
        $.getJSON("./Handler.ashx", function(data) {
            $("#TextBox3").autocomplete({
                source: data
            });
        });           
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks all, I realized my problem was with my handler. I had previously coded it to work with a querystring passed from autocomplete and forgot to comment out. This was causing a exception error. This code posted works great.

Answer (score 0):

The AJAX call is asynchronous, so you are trying to use the data before it arrives. Use the data inside the callback function:

```
$(function () {
  $.getJSON("./Handler.ashx", function(data) {
    $("#TextBox3").autocomplete({
      source: data
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Is the `.` in the URL actually valid?

Comment: @Craig: Yes, a single period means "the current directory".

Comment: Thanks, I totally didn't realize that a single `.` worked from client side but I knew that `../` does so that was a silly assumption by me :) Oh so many details and I let this one get away.

Comment: Yes, Im using a relative path because visual studio debug will puke without it since the web site doesnt run at the root of the debug web server. I tried publishing to the webserver and still no good. Script #2 still works fine though, but I cna see its making a call with every key press.